# Using Neural Networks Without Training Them

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, game-development

My task for my university assignment is to create AI for a "MOBA" style strategy game. I have looked into using neural networks for this. I cannot see any need to train the network beforehand.

In other words, would it still be considered as a neural network if I hard code in the weights and simply apply minor weight changes at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Neural network is one thing (a structure of neurons, synapses, etc.) and the learning algorithm is a completely different thing.

So if you ask whether a NN without learning algorithm can still be called NN I think the answer is yes, it can.